# Laravel Авторизация с ролями многие ко многим

Tags: php, laravel, auth, laravel-5.7

пытаюсь сделать авторизацию на ларавел с двумя ролями. Не понимаю как проверить права пользователя. Сделал стандартные три таблицы, user, roles и role_user, две модели Role и User, связи в моделях

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
    }
```

Если я правильно понял, проверять права я буду в посреднике, и везде по этой теме пишут что права можено получить строчкой

```
$user->role->id
```

но это не работает, потому что по $user->role я получаю большой массив с кучей ненужной инфы, до которой нужно добираться через индексы массива. И даже если я делаю

```
$role = $user->role->toArray();
           echo "<pre>";
           print_r($role);
```

то почему то получаю два одинаковых массива

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [pivot] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => admin
            [pivot] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Как мне это все красиво сделать? 
Laravel Framework 5.7.25

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555697/check-if-belongstomany-relation-exists-laravel

Просто проверьте существует ли такая роль у текушего юзера:

> ```
> $client = Client::find(1);
> $exists = $client->products->contains($product_id);
> ```

(Смысл тот же)))

Answer (score 0):

Несколько одинаковых ролей у пользователя ты получаешь по той причине, что несколько раз вызвал метод `$user->roles()->attach($role)`. Есть метод связи   `sync($roleId)` or `syncWithoutDetaching()` (доки по связям в помощь). А чтобы разрешения проверять (`permissions` или `abilities`), надо иметь модель, связанную с ролью m-2-m связью. Роль - это просто группировка разрешений со всеми вытекающими